# Equivalent of a PHP loop in possibly one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called 'Visits' that stores MAC addresses along with their timestamps. I have the task to check each day's MAC addresses against those of the previous days and if found, update them as 'Repeat' in today's records with the number of visits made so far (excluding today).

I have written the following PHP code that does the job nicely but the problem is that today it's taking 586.4 seconds to execute (checking 1,500 MACs against 70,000 from the previous 40 days) and it will surely become worse with each passing day.

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT MAC FROM `Visits` WHERE TimeStamp=:TimeStamp");
$STH->bindParam(':TimeStamp', $unixDataDate);
$STH->execute();
while ($r = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $MAC=$r['MAC'];
    $STH2 = $DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM `Visits` WHERE MAC=:MAC AND TimeStamp<:TimeStamp");
    $STH2->bindParam(':MAC', $MAC);
    $STH2->bindParam(':TimeStamp', $unixDataDate);
    $STH2->execute();
    $prevVisits=$STH2->fetchColumn();
    if ($prevVisits>0) {
            $STH3 = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE `Visits` SET RepeatVisitor=:RepeatVisitor WHERE MAC=:MAC AND TimeStamp=:TimeStamp");
            $STH3->bindParam(':RepeatVisitor', $prevVisits);
            $STH3->bindParam(':MAC', $MAC);
            $STH3->bindParam(':TimeStamp', $unixDataDate);
            $STH3->execute();
    }
}
```

Now I tried several ways to construct a query to do this job and compare execution times but I couldn't get the same results. Any help as to whether it's possible to do this task in one inexpensive query and how to format it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Visits.TimeStamp is a date

```
UPDATE Visits 
SET RepeatVisitor = 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Visits as v2 WHERE v2.MAC = Visits.MAC and v2.TimeStamp!=Visits.TimeStamp AMD v2.TimeStamp>'[40 days ago generated in PHP]') 
WHERE Visits.TimeStamp = '[Yesterday generated in PHP]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed indexes on both the MAC and Timestamp column? If not, these should speed things up considerably.

Also, move the `prepare` statements outside of the while loop, you're preparing the same query over and over, which kind of misses the point. Prepare once, execute more often.